# How do you properly clear Aurelia binding of a complex object?

Tags: aurelia

***Background:*** I'm trying to create a form using Aurelia. I have a person object that I would like to be able to fill in data for. If the user knows some identifying information about the person's family, they can enter it in an input and a select box will be displayed to allow the user to select the individual from that family for this particular form. The form will then fill in any information it knows about that individual into input fields allowing the user to overwrite any of the information if necessary. The form also allows them to clear the selected person if they want to choose another one.

Most of the functionality seems to work as expected, but when I try to allow the user to clear out the selected person, I'm seeing some behavior that I wouldn't have expected.

---

I have created a [GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=5cb00c408da19594c22c494a25ea2a42&sha=6923b0d5a985a718ceaa7f6453f4a582fc47e35a). The bottom pane is working as I would expect, after the user gets data, selects a person and then clears their selection, they are provided with the select element again. If you uncomment the input element, you will see that the user now ***has to click the clear action twice*** before they see the select element again. ***Why?***

How can I update the application so that the user will only need to clear out the person once and the select box will appear again to allow the user to make another selection?

---

If you have an Aurelia application, you should be able to reproduce this by replacing the `app.html` with the following:

```
<template>
  <select value.bind="val2" if.bind="opts2 && !val2">
    <option repeat.for="opt of opts2" model.bind="opt">${opt.firstName}</option>
  </select>
  <div if.bind="!opts2 || val2">
    <span>${val2.firstName}</span>
    <button click.delegate="clearVal2()" if.bind="val2">Clear</button>
  </div>
  <button click.delegate="getOpts2()">Get</button>
  <div>${val2.blah}</div>
  <!--<input type="text" value.bind="val2.blah"/>-->
</template>
```

An the `app.js` with this:

```
export class App {
  opts2;
  val2;

  getOpts2(){
    this.opts2 = [
      undefined,
      {
        blah: 1,
        firstName: 'foo',
        address: {
          line1: '123 Main St.'
        }
      },
      {
        blah: 2,
        firstName: 'bar',
        address: {
          line1: '456 Other Wy.'
        }
      }
    ];
  }

  clearVal2(){
    this.val2 = null;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

***UPDATE***
If I put the input in a custom element and bind to that, things seem to work as expected. The values that I'm putting into my form though aren't in one location that I could utilize a custom element for. [I have updated the Gist with an example](https://gist.run/?id=5cb00c408da19594c22c494a25ea2a42&sha=05f0868450c007267ecd3b03ccbeabd4f351ba04).

How can I achieve the same functionality without the need for a custom element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that you are allowing the user to either select a value from the list or create a completely new entry, I would tend towards separating the value selected in the list and the data backing up the text boxes. Whenever the value of the `select` changes, I would set the value of the object backing the text boxes to the value of the `select`. The way I chose to do this in my sample code is to use the `observable` decorator on the value the `select` is bound to.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=e4b594eaa452b47d9b3984e7f9b04109**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <select value.bind="val" if.bind="opts && !val">
      <option repeat.for="opt of opts" model.bind="opt">${opt.firstName}</option>
    </select>
    <button click.delegate="getOpts()">Get</button>
  </div>
  <div if.bind="!opts || person">
    <span>First Name: ${person.firstName}</span>
    <button click.delegate="resetForm()" if.bind="val">Clear Selection</button>
  </div>
  Address: <input type="text" value.bind="person.address.line1" />

  <hr />
  val
  <pre><code>
    ${toJSON(val)}
  </code></pre>
  person
  <pre><code>
    ${toJSON(person)}
  </code></pre>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
import {observable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {

  @observable val = null;
  person = {};

  getOpts(){
    this.opts = [
      null,
      {
        blah: 1,
        firstName: 'foo',
        address: {
          line1: '123 Main St.'
        }
      },
      {
        blah: 2,
        firstName: 'bar',
        address: {
          line1: '456 Other Wy.'
        }
      }
    ];
  }

  valChanged() {
    this.person = this.val;
    console.log("set person");
  }

  resetForm(){
    this.val = null;
    console.log("reset val");
  }

  toJSON(value) {
    if(!(value === false) && !value) {
      return '';
    }

    return JSON.stringify(value);
  }
}
```

You can see something interesting is happening when I reset the form. Aurelia is creating the properties necessary for bindings to `person` (namely `person.address.line1` when we set `person = null`. But it doesn't create a `firstName` property, b/c that property isn't being bound until `person` stops being falsey.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. It works, I just wish I understood why. This seems like an unnecessary indirection.

Comment: I could argue that you're correct, or I could argue that it is a necessary indirection. In the use case you are presenting, I think that separating the value chosen in the dropdown from the data entered in the textbox is the correct way to do this. Since the user can enter information without selecting anything in the dropdown, it makes sense to separate the two.

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty I'm not sure why, but if you add if.bind="val2"on the input element, it clears the value and the select button returns.

```
<input type="text" if.bind="val2" value.bind="val2.blah"/>
```

Hope this (slightly) helps

Comment: In addition to Naadof's answer, I think this problem happens because even though you are setting `this.val = null` there are other elements bound to this property, so `this.val` is set again after calling `clear()`. (if you print `this.val` in page you see that it is not null). This `<input type="text" if.bind="val" value.bind="val.address.line1" />` should solve you problem

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but ultimately this doesn't help. They need to be able to enter information in the address field even if they don't choose one of the family members. I can't have the input disappear as well. I just need that input to clear out. 3 options: enter all new information, select person and have all information input for them or enter person and have the ability to overwrite some of the information.

Comment: apologies @peinearydevelopment , misunderstood your question. Looked at your updated gist and tinkered with it - is this what you're after? If so, I'll edit my answer.

https://gist.run/?id=7d488537da23a465252e08c22a35f524

Comment: @Naadof Thanks so much for your comment. When I went to the Gist though, I wasn't able to see what you had changed.

Comment: it was simply changing   <select value.bind="val2" if.bind="opts2 && !val2"> to <select value.bind="val2" if.bind="opts2 && !val2.blah"> . IMO, you don't need anything more complicated.

Did you test the Gist? it works how I think you want it to work

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to simply use the `with` attribute to scope the input.

https://gist.run/?id=7b9d230f7d3c6dc8c13cefdd7be50c7f

```
<template>
  <template with.bind="val.address">
    <input value.bind="line1" />
  </template>
</template>
```

Although I agree that mixing the logic of selections and inputs like that is probably not the best idea :)